# Apache Airflow - Same Database for multiple Airflow Server

Tags: database, airflow

DOes anyone know how to set up 1 single metadata store for multiple Airflow Servers?

I am talking about something here - https://www.astronomer.io/guides/airflow-database/

But with the intent to run multiple airflow instances which can use single server

[image]

Comment: I did not get your question. Are you asking a single server with multiple DB instances in it ? This is what we do with AWS aurora Postgres type. Please let me know if its otherwise ?

Comment: @hopeIsTheonlyWeapon      No that's not what I meant, I wanted to have multiple airflow instances, who connect to a single database to store their metadata. i.e. monolithic/multitenant Metadata store for Airflow

Comment: @ha9u63ar Did you mean running a High Availability setup? If that is the case, you could just pass the same database credentials to each Airflow webserver - it should be able to automatically connect.

If you intend to run multiple separate Airflow instances, then I'm afraid you can't use the same database. You CAN, however, create multiple "databases" on the same Postgres "Server". In which case, you will have same Host URI but the database name would differ for each instance.